# How put a div editable and save after in same page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a login form and when I login with admin account I want to put Home page editable. Home page have DIVs.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
           window.alert('Welcome!')
           window.location.href='Home.html'
           </SCRIPT>");
}
```

Ok this code is working and I can login successfully but now I want to open Home page but editable and save online.

Comment: Did you even try ? The code you're showing has no relation with you question. Make a page "editable" is a hard work, requires you to print things from the database, and then edit values in the database from the admin. Try, and if you have a problem come back with a real question.

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here.

Comment: You seem new and should start web design with reading some books or following some tutorials in the area you are trying to develop

Comment: As pointed out in one of the answers, this is "Too much to cover in one question". You need to narrow down the focus of your question, as it is much too broad to actually have a useful answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Too much to cover in one question ... you should read a little further about the subject since there are several ways to do it.

One thing is **how you will edit the content** ... you can use  html5 [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) or some more elaborated solution like a WYSIWYG Editor (what you see is what you get) like [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) ... google about it and you will find lots of editors.

Another thing is **how you will send the data to the server** ... you can use a simple form, ajax, sockets ... as you see it is also a complex thing, but you can start with a [jquery load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) since it's very simple to implement.

Lastly, **how you will save the data** ... I'm guessing you will use your SQL DB. How you will handle the data in the server is another deep subject. Worry about **caching** results and queries from the beginning will save you from a lot of trouble later.

Hope this info will help you start building your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 attribute `contentEditable` which is supported by all modern browsers.

```
<div id="editme">
      xyz
      xyz
      xyz
</div>

<?php
if(is_admin())
{
?>

<div id="edit"></div>
<div id="save"></div>

<script>
    $(function(ev){
       ev.preventDefault();

       $("#edit").on('click', function(){
           $("#editme").prop('contentEditable', TRUE);
       });


      $("#save").on('click', function(){
           var url = "insert.php";
           var data = $("#editme").html();

           $.post(url, data);
       });
    })
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: My question is how to validate when the admin enter put the home page editable.

Comment: You can do it with a simple `if` statement. Check edits.

Comment: how u can see in my code i have the validation when is admin or not, if is admin i receive one message saying Welcome and i need to put some code there to put page editable.